# JSF-API 2.0 is not in Maven central repo?

Tags: java, jsf, maven

I'm trying to add `jsf-api` and `jsf-impl` dependencies to a project, and can't find them in Maven central repo. Are they there? I'm interested in 2.0+.

Mojarra site suggests to add a link to their repository:

```
<repository>
  <id>java.net</id>
  <name>java.net</name>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
</repository>
```

But this is against Maven convention not to use third-party repositories, only Maven central..

Comment: I don't do Maven, so here's just a link to the Mojarra dev site where I've seen some Maven-specific examples: http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html It may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add the repository reference directly in your POM, you can add it in Maven's [settings file](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html). Alternatively, consider a repository manager such as [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Add this repository http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/faces/ to your maven project and use this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.x</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.x</version>
</dependency>
```